# China -> Hong Kong -> China layover, visa needed?

Tags: visas, china, hong-kong

I have a very long layover in Guangzhou, and I was looking forward to heading down to Hong Kong, before having to head back up to the airport in China. I am an Australian citizen, and I know there is a (72?) hour visa free period for me since I am transiting. However, this brings into the question of going to Hong Kong. Do I need a multi-entry visa for China or can I re-enter at the land border with the visa free period?
Thanks!

Comment: The 72h TWoV only applies to air transits. To reenter China, you'd need a visa, but that can be applied at the border.

Answer (score 1):

You are visa-exempt in Hong Kong aa you are an Australian citizen for 90 days:

> [image]

([Hong Kong GOV Website](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html))

A visa is required for China as you don't meet any requirements for [visa-free](http://au.china-embassy.org/eng/ls/vfc/t1038742.htm) entry. You can view visa types on the [China Embassy in Australia website.](http://au.china-embassy.org/eng/ls/vfc/t1038740.htm)